# Is there a way to store a DocumentReference within the data created in Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store the Firestore unique Id within the data that i am creating. I believe the unique id is created after the data has been processed which is why my code beneath results in nil. Is this not possible?

```
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("all_posts").addDocument(data: [
                
            "author": [
                "uid": userId,
                "username": "John"
            ],
            "PostId": ref!.documentID,
                     
        ]) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
```

Could this be achieved with a uuidString somehow?

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you'll want to:

1. First create a reference to a new document by calling `document()`.
2. Then write to this new reference.

If you look at the third code snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), this can be done with:

```
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("all_posts").document()
ref.setData((data: [                
    "author": [
        "uid": userId,
        "username": "John"
    ],
    "PostId": ref!.documentID,
             
]) { (err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err)
```

Comment: calling "doc()" gave the me the error "CollectionReference has no member doc()". However ending with "document()" works flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah, it's indeed `document()` on Swift. Thanks for flagging. I updated it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your own unique ID:

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let data: [String: Any] = [
    "author": [
        "uid": userId,
        "username": "John"
    ],
    "PostId": uuid
]

Firestore.firestore().collection("all_posts").document(uuid).setData(data, merge: true) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Or let Firestore generate a unique ID:

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("all_posts").document()
let docId = docRef.documentID
let data: [String: Any] = [
    "author": [
        "uid": userId,
        "username": "John"
    ],
    "PostId": docId
]

docRef.setData(data, merge: true) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

`setData(merge: true)` will create the document if it doesn't already exist and merge this data into it if it does. You can, of course, just add the document outright without this sort of safety net. And you can also take a functional approach to this without using variables and nils since none of these values are optional.